# How to find which column has special characters in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I would like to find out which column has special characters in a file

For example, I have the data below:

```
11|abc|ac♠|12
12|aac|be•|2♣
13|cj♦|jkd|32
```

Desired output:

```
1|3
2|3|4
3|2
```

I want the record number along with the column numbers that have special characters.

Comment: What do you consider as a "special character"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, the output doesn't seem to match the input.

Comment: what character encoding are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define *special character*.  I will assume that you mean anything outside of the normal ASCII range.  Try:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{r=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /[^\t -~]/) r=r OFS i; if (r) print NR r} ' OFS='|' File
1|3
2|3|4
3|2
```

#### How it works:

- `-F'|'`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator for input.
- `r=""`

  This initializes `r` to an empty string.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /[^\t -~]/) r=r OFS i`

  This goes through each field on a line and, if it contains a character outside the normal ASCII range, it adds the field number to `r`.

  In an awk regex, `\t` is a tab character and `-~` matches any character from blank (ASCII 32) to `~` (ASCII 126).  These are what we have defined as "normal" characters.  In awk regex, `^` means "not".  So,  `[^\t -~]` matches any character that is not in our list of normal characters.

  You are free to add or remove characters from my normal list as your please.
- `if (r) print NR r}`

  If, after going through all the fields, `r` is nonempty, then print out the record number and the value of `r`.
- `OFS='|'`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the record separator for output.

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -F'|' '
    {
        r=""
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ($i ~ /[^\t -~]/)
                r=r OFS i
        if (r)
            print NR r
    } ' OFS='|' File
```